Custom Date output based on formula

I am attempting to create a custom date output formula in Cell E2, to recreate the formatting used in cell A2, using the value in cell B2, and the date logic and extracted date information from cell A2. I am having issues, incorporating the "TEXT" function in the formulas, to attain desired output.
Cell C2 contains the result from formula:
=IFERROR(IF($B2>20,DATEVALUE(LEFT($A2,10))-90,IF($B2<=20,DATEVALUE(LEFT($A2,10))-60,IF($B2>10,DATEVALUE(LEFT($A2,10))-60,IF($B2<=10,DATEVALUE(LEFT($A2,10))-30,""))))),"")
Cell C3 contains the result from formula:
=IFERROR(IF($B2>20,DATEVALUE(LEFT($A2,10))-90&RIGHT($A2,11),IF($B2<=20,DATEVALUE(LEFT($A2,10))-60&RIGHT($A2,11),IF($B2>10,DATEVALUE(LEFT($A2,10))-60&RIGHT($A2,11),IF($B2<=10,DATEVALUE(LEFT($A2,10))-30&RIGHT($A2,11),"")))),"")

Could you explain the logic in words? Why would 24 result in 3 months prior to initial value?

24 is a value of effort, and effects the lag between the date ranges. Formula two in cell C3 shows the effect of different lag ranges triggered by the formula. 24 being greater than 20 triggers 90 days of lag.

Does this work on your end? --> =TEXT((--TEXTBEFORE(A2," - ",-1))-LOOKUP(B2,{0,11,21},{30,60,90}),"mmm - e - ")&TEXTAFTER(A2," - ",2)

https://1drv.ms/i/s!ArbTv3PQHlEGeAM0k4yrNNwNKKk?e=sUuoL6
It works in most all instance of application, except for instances shown here.
There are no conditions for returning 2nd Half or 1st Half.  The intent of the formula is to capture the date and year, apply the 30, 60 or 90 day gap then grabbing the 11 characters from the right of the cell, and adding it onto the end of the text string.

What value have you taken for those data? like in the above example you have shown 24 which results in 3 months back, but in the new screenshot it shows all going forward

Formula used to solve: =IF(B2<=10,TEXT(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(LEFT($A2,10)),-2)+1,"mmm - yyyy")&RIGHT(A2,11),IF(AND(B2>10,B2<=20),TEXT(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(LEFT($A2,10)),-3)+1,"mmm - yyyy")&RIGHT(A2,11),IF(B2>20,TEXT(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(LEFT($A2,10)),-4)+1,"mmm - yyyy")&RIGHT(A2,11),"")))
